# Collapse overloads for copy and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, move-semantics, api-design

Many methods have overloads for copy and move semantics. For example, construct and assignment from another type,

```
T(const U&);
T(U&&);

T& operator=(const U&);
T& operator=(U&&);
```

More often than not, implementations of the two overloads are quite similar, which kind of leads to code redundancy. So I'm considering collapsing the two into one.

One method I find actually in use is to pass by value and let the value construction do the trick. For example,

```
constexpr atomic_shared_ptr(shared_ptr<T> desired) noexcept;
```

where `desired` may be either copy-constructed or move-constructed. However, pass-by-value is no panacea. Again, take `atomic_shared_ptr` as an example,

```
bool compare_exchange_weak(std::shared_ptr<T>&, const std::shared_ptr<T>& d...
bool compare_exchange_weak(std::shared_ptr<T>&, std::shared_ptr<T>&& d...
```

Unlike the construction/assignment case, depending on the compare result, `d` may not always be copied. If `d` is passed by value, it will always be copied, and the copy is not cheap.

Another solution I come up with is to use forwarding reference.

```
template <typename U>
bool compare_exchange_weak(std::shared_ptr<T>&, U&& d...
  ... std::forward<U>(d) ...
```

However, this formulation is too permissible/tolerable.

Any other idea or suggestion?

Comment: If something "leads to code redundancy", then refactor out the duplicate code. Copy and move constructors have fundamentally different purposes; ditto for move/non-move assignment operators. If each set of them has a lot of code in common, factor it out.

Comment: @Lingxi: "*More often than not, implementations of the two overloads are quite similar, which kind of leads to code redundancy.*" About 99% of the time when these two functions have "quite similar" implementations, you're doing is an element-wise copy/move. If you have one member that needs special copy/move handling, then that one member ought to handle that *internally*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, this can be done through a forwarding reference. But the signature is too admissible.

Comment: @Lingxi: That's not what I meant. I meant that you use `= default` for the copy and move constructors. If a member needs special copy/move handling, then that member should be of a type that has its own special copy/move handling. So if you have a type that stores an integer that represents a file handle, you should not store an `int`; you should store a move-only type that has its move constructor/assignment operators that transfer ownership of the handle. The outer class should just use the defaults.

Comment: @NicolBolas Agreed. However, what I'm having problem with is not the standard copy/move constructor/assignment operator. Note that `T` and `U` may be different types. I guess `= default` won't work.

Comment: @Lingxi: But *why* won't it work? If you're storing pointers you own and need to delete them, then you should wrap those pointers individually in a `unique_ptr` or similar construct. That way, the class storing those pointers doesn't need specialized copy/move constructors. Only low-level classes should need specialized copy/move constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could constrain the template:

```
template <typename U>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>,std::shared_ptr<T>>,bool> 
compare_exchange_weak(std::shared_ptr<T>&, U&& d...
  ... std::forward<U>(d) ...
```

With the [new concept syntax proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0745r0.pdf) it could be more readable:

```
template<class T,class V>
concept Same_d = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>,std::decay_t<U>>;

bool compare_exchange_weak(std::shared_ptr<T>&, Same_d{U}<std::shared_ptr<T>>&& d...
  ... std::forward<U>(d) ...
```